# How can I inject Modules in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, design-patterns

I'm using Module pattern, now I wanted to know is that possible to inject one module into another like AngularJs.

Below is sample code that I've tried.

module.js

```
var AnotherModule = (function () {

    function AnotherModule() {
        this.anotherFunction = function () {
            alert('Inside another Module');
        }
    }
    return AnotherModule;

})(window);

var AnotherModule = new AnotherModule();

var Module = (function (window, AnotherModule) {

    function Module(AnotherModule) {

        var privateMethod = function() {

        }

        this.getName = function (brand) {
            console.log('Inside get Name');
            console.log(AnotherModule);
        }

    }
    return Module;

})(window, AnotherModule);


var module = new Module();
module.getName();
```

Comment: using the same variable name for instances and definitions does not help! For example, when you do `(window, AnotherModule);` are you attempting to pass the definition, or the instance you created earlier to that IIFE?

Comment: Yes, but why not just use Angular?

Comment: I'm very much dependent on SEO, as per my knowledge we can't achieve that using AngularJs.

Comment: Might want to revisit that assumption.